# Webfaction Django 1.4.1: serving static and media with custom nginx build

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, webfaction

I have a custom nginx build for my project and everything works fine except I'm confused about serving static files using the same nginx server (below you can see my config file) recently tried to set `root=/home/USERNAME/media/app/` and `root= /home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/medialaw;` also created static only applications in control panel and pointed `extra_info` to my `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` respectively but all things failed.

Can anyone help me with it, may be someone already faced such a challenge?

```
server {
    listen   MY_PORT;
    server_name USERNAME.webfactional.com;

    access_log /home/USERNAME/logs/user/nginx/app_access.log;
    error_log  /home/USERNAME/logs/user/nginx/app_error.log;

    root /home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/medialaw;

   location /m {
        alias /home/USERNAME/media/app/media;

        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location /s {
        alias /home/imanhodjaev/media/app/static;

        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
         }
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT/;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

> I've posted this question recently on webfaction Q&A site
>   http://community.webfaction.com/questions/10535/django-141-serving-static-and-media-with-custom-nginx-build

Thanks,

Sultan

Comment: are you making use of collectstatic?

Comment: @Reinbach yes I did collect static and it worked nice, all of the static contents in their places

Comment: What do you mean by "all things failed"? What's not working? What do you see? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Django website works fine. But for static files I've 404 error from nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved this is how configuration looks like so far

#### Nginx

```
server {
    listen   MY_PORT;
    server_name USERNAME.webfactional.com;

    access_log /home/USERNAME/logs/user/nginx/app_access.log;
    error_log  /home/USERNAME/logs/user/nginx/app_error.log;

    root /home/USERNAME/media/app;

    location /m {
        alias /home/USERNAME/media/app/media;
    }

    location /s/ {
        alias /home/imanhodjaev/media/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT/;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

#### Webfaction configuration from control panel

Deleted two static only apps filled required fields and set `extra_info` for static and media locations respectively.

Thanks,

Sultan